# How do I prevent Mercurial patches from being pulled?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, patch, mercurial-queue

So far I haven't been able to find a clear answer, though it's possible that the answer is "change your workflow".

I've just started playing around with Mercurial's patch queue and I can see some serious power in it. It seems pretty awesome. In my tests, I've discovered that if you have a patch queue in `repo1`, and you pull from `repo2`, you can do some bad things. For example:

1. Create repos 1, and clone it.
2. Enable the queue on `repo1`
3. Make some commits and some patches on `repo1`
4. Pull changes to `repo2`
5. On `repo1` un-apply(pop?) all your patches
6. Pull changes to `repo2`

Now you'll see two different branches - which makes sense from a certain viewpoint. However, since my patches aren't a part of `repo1`'s history (at least until they're applied), it seems like there should be a way to tell mercurial that my patches are off-limits, and only provide what's in the "official history".

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I realize that I could create a stand-alone repository, clone it, and use the queue in my clone, but it adds a little extra complexity to my workflow. Also it seems like it might be harder to get other people working with patches, too.

Comment: The slightly dirty secret of mq patches is that they *are* part of your repo's history while they are active (`qpush`-ed).  Check the log.  `qpop` strips the patch from the repo history.  And `qpush`-ing again creates a new, albeit similar changeset with a new id.  So, `mq` changes history.  Either `qpop -all` before pulls or pushes to other repos or try the `phases` approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mercurial [phases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/phases) may be the answer to this.

Starting with Mercurial v2.1, you can configure `mq` changesets to automatically be marked `secret`.  `secret` changesets are ignored by `incoming/pull` and `outgoing/push` commands.

To enable this behavior, you need to add the following to your config:

```
[mq]
secret = True
```

Once enabled, it behaves as follows:

```
$ hg qpush --all
applying my-patch
now at: my-patch

$ hg phase -r .
16873: secret

$hg outgoing
comparing with https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg
searching for changes
no changes found (ignored 1 secret changesets)
```

Comment: Beautiful! I actually just found out about phases today as well, and this solution worked perfectly, thanks!